# How can I view new files that would be introduced on merging branches?

Tags: git

Imagine a branch named A. We fork a branch named B from it, and we commit stuff around. Some of the commits are modifiying existing files, while some of them will be introducing new files.

If I switch back from B to A, is there a way to find out what new files B will introduce when I merge them?

Answer (score 2):

You can run `git merge --no-commit --no-ff B`, then see the changes and then rollback, or you can try `git diff` between last commits in A and B branches and examine this diff on order to see new files. If your branch B is branched from HEAD of branch A, there should not be any conflicts in `git diff` would run fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `--stat` option for `git diff` will give you a list:

```
git diff --stat A..B
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `--diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)…[*]]` option of `git diff` to filter out the `A` added files, or whichever is the important one for you.